# Script not close the section

Tags: batch-file, winscp

This script cat and paste files from folder on FTP server. This is work but from some reason after running the section are not closed and I'm need to rate manually "exit".

```
 @echo off

"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" ^
  /log="C:\WinSCP.log" /ini=nul ^
  /command ^
    "open sftp://alma_972icc_lev%%40customers.eu@custdata-dc03.hosted.exlibrisgroup.com:10022/ -hostkey=""ssh-rsa 4096 upqTBzuxy+fGrA4+dFQaWXmIq7/E1CwyAjqRSwq9eQo"" -privatekey=""C:\FTP_KEY\id_rsa.ppk"" -rawsettings AgentFwd=1 ProxyPort=1" ^
    "get -delete /production/Alma/* C:\exlibris\" 

    "exit /b"

set WINSCP_RESULT=%ERRORLEVEL%
if %WINSCP_RESULT% equ 0 (
  echo Success
) else (
  echo Error
)

exit /b %WINSCP_RESULT%
```

Answer (score 3):

You could be missing the `^` after the `get -delete`... line. This would cause the shell to try to run `"exit /b"` as a separate command instead of passing the string to WinSCP.

Edit: Also, the WinSCP command to exit is simply `exit`, this is passed to WinSCP and Windows Command Prompt does not handle it. Using `exit /b` causes WinSCP to complain about too many parameters and exit with an error.

I have adapted the code to my machine and it exits cleanly without any action needed.

To summarise, the two lines should be:

```
    "get -delete /production/Alma/* C:\exlibris\" ^

    "exit"
```

Comment: nope, I tray this is not work.

Comment: I have adapted the code for my computer and it exits. Are you sure the line is exactly `"get -delete /production/Alma/* C:\exlibris\" ^` (space caret)?